# Aggregating logs label’s values in one line

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I’m trying to create a table with an aggregation of values in the same field but without any calculation function.

I have a Loki LogQL query that transforms to a table with three labels. I want to do a “group by” with two of the labels, and the third one will be aggregated to have all the values in the same line together. For example:

The logs line from the query are:

```
Apple Buy 20
Apple Buy 20
Apple Sell 45
Apple Sell 45
Banana Buy 30
Banana Buy 30
Banana Buy 20
Banana Buy 20
Banana Sell 45
Banana Sell 45
```

And after transformations (Labels to fields, Filter by name, Group by - on all three labels, Organize fields), the table looks like this:

[Table first example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX6WL.png)

- I couldn't add a picture yet

And I want it to become like this:

[Table after wanted change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWgeA.png)

So for Type Banana with Process Buy, all the values are aggregated together like in a list or vector (We can have the values ordered, but it’s not necessary, the Value is a string of a number).

I have been trying to do the change between the first table to the second and have encountered difficulties completing this change.

Any help would be very appreciated.

I have posted this also if the Grafana community and asking this here as well in the hope of a wider reach and finding an answer.